# Google App Script throws compile time error when the function length is more than 100 lines

Tags: compilation, google-apps-script

I am facing a weird problem with Google App Script. If the function is less than 100 lines then, it compiles successfully. If I add a line so that the function length is 101 lines, it throws compile time error.

I thought that I am missing something in my function and hence tried with a simple function.
Can you please help if there is any such limit and is there any way to increase this limit?

```
function myFunction() {
  var i = 1;
  i = 1;
  i = 1;
  ........
  ........
  i = 1;
  i = 1;
  i = 1;
}

// This should be 101th line.
```

Comment: I've tried this with functions that are 99 to 111 lines long, and I'm having no problem. What error are you seeing? See [Issue 2237](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2237), maybe you've got mismatched braces, and just can't tell because of this bug?

Answer (score 0):

When you say it throws an error are you just referring to incorrect code coloring? There's a known issue with coloring functions longer than 100 lines but the code will still run happily.